# Parse Server - JS - Query to return Observable

Tags: parse-platform, promise, async-await, rxjs, observable

I am finally upgrading my code to [Parse JS SDK > 2.0](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/2.0.0.md) and am struggling to convert an existing function that returns an Observable after a query. I know that my issue is that query.find() now needs to be async/await but really lost on the best practices here. I've tried creating the observable first and using toPromise(), using .defer and also tried returning the observable inside query.find().then but I'm sure that's laughable.

Any guidance on this would be most appreciated!

```
  getAttending(eventId) {
    const event = new this.Event();
    event.id = eventId;
    const query = new Parse.Query(this._parseInvites);
    query.limit(1000);
    query.equalTo("event_objectId", event);

    return Observable.fromPromise(query.find())
      .map((arrEventInvites) => {
        return arrEventInvites.reduce((total, invite) => {
          var countGuest = parseInt(invite.get("invite_guest"), 10);
          var countChild = parseInt(invite.get("invite_childcount"), 10);

          total += 1;

          if (isNaN(countGuest) || (!isNaN(countGuest) && !countGuest)) {
            total += 0;
          } else {
            total += countGuest;
          }

          if (isNaN(countChild) || (!isNaN(countChild) && !countChild)) {
            total += 0;
          } else {
            total += countChild;
          }

          return total;
        }, 0);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.parseProvider.handleError(err);
        return Observable.throw(0);
      });
  }
```

Comment: `query.find()` still returns a Promise and you are not required to use the async/await format. Your code should continue working and I believe it is actually written in the right way since you are using `Observable.fromPromise` function.

Comment: Which library are you using for Observables? Unless I'm mistaken, Parse doesn't implement observables. Even with RxJS (one of the more popular implementations), how to do this differs depending on which version you're using. Newer versions use `from()` to convert arrays, iterables, and promises instead of `fromPromise()`. If you can tell us which libraries you're using and/or what errors you're getting, that might help.

Comment: @MrkSef - Yep using RxJS@5.5.12 at the moment for the Observables. Can't say I understand the benefit of using an observable here but this is pulling attendance counts for each event a user has, so there can be multiple events at a time.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo - It technically works but in my template I am using {{event?.attending$ | async}} and event.attending$ = this.getAttending(event.id); (the above function. I've noticed that the correct counts will flash and then disappear, my guess was that the Observable wasn't waiting on the query to finish but I might be wrong.